# send an e-mail from a form using jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, contacts

I already spent a lot of time searching for this.

I need to send a form from site to my e-mail (with attach), but the site can not refresh, I need to stay on the same page.

Exemple:

> Index.html -> mailscript.js -> mail.php

I dont need to validate e-mail or fill required fields ( but it would be good ).

Comment: You're looking for something called AJAX. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: @Dolchio avoid sharing links to w3schools website. They did more harm  than good to the community.

Comment: not refresh - or simply return to the same page.

Comment: @Dagon i cant return to the same page 'cus my site its only in one page and change content with jquery.. so i need ajax script !

Comment: im sure it can be done with out, but your call